# How can I add a health check to a Sagemaker Endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

My sagemaker endpoint has a /ping and according to AWS Cloudwatch it gets pinged about every 5 seconds:

```
10.32.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2018:08:08:35 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "-" "AHC/2.0"
```

However, I don't see what would happen if this ping would fail. Where can I configure the health check?

Answer (score 3):

If the pings fail consistently during Endpoint creation, we will treat the container as unhealthy and fail the Endpoint with an error message:

"ClientError: The primary container for production variant [xxx] did not pass the ping health check. Please check CloudWatch logs for this endpoint."

If the pings fail consistently after Endpoint creation (Endpoint is up and running), we will try our best to replace the instance while keeping your Endpoint in service.

Here is the documentation page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html#your-algorithms-inference-algo-ping-requests

You can implement more sophisticated health check. However the ping response should return within 2 seconds timeout.

Hope this helps!

-Han

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SageMaker is a managed service and the responsibility of the service team is to make sure that it is available. They are monitoring your endpoint and will replace the containers and instances for you if needed.

You can monitor the performance of your endpoint using the CloudWatch metrics (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatch.html ), but it is tuned more toward the right selection of the instance type and the number of instances that you want to have (your cost) and not on the (ping) availability.

Comment: So what will happen if the ping fails?

Comment: In https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html I found "Amazon SageMaker does not currently run this health check continuously. This is intended to prevent an unstable container going into service against an endpoint at startup." - could you expand on this?

Comment: SageMaker is balancing between a managed service and being open for every specific container that you would want to run in it. If you are using a container that the service team optimized, the health check functionality is well defined, but if your container is not well behaving (slow or wrong response to ping, for example) or slow to start, you might get into bad cycles of restarts that can affect the availability of your endpoint. 
Please read carefully the guidelines of the containers, and consult with your solutions architect or technical support for any issue that you have.