# Sagemaker Batch Transform Error "Model container failed to respond to ping; Ensure /ping endpoint is implemented and responds with an HTTP 200 status"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs, amazon-sagemaker

My task is to do large scale inference via Sagemaker Batch Transform.

I have been following the tutorial: bring your own container, https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.ipynb

I have encountered many problems and solved them by searching stack overflow. However there is one problem that still causes the trouble.

When I run the same code and same dataset using 20 EC2 instances simultaneously, sometimes I get the error "Model container failed to respond to ping; Please ensure /ping endpoint is implemented and responds with an HTTP 200 status", and sometimes I don't.

What I find most frustrating is that, I have already do nothing for /ping (see code below)

```
@app.route("/ping", methods=["GET"])
def ping():
    """Determine if the container is working and healthy. In this sample container, we declare it healthy if we can load the model successfully."""
    # health = ScoringService.get_model() is not None  # You can insert a health check here
    # status = 200 if health else 404
    
    status = 200
    return flask.Response(response="\n", status=status, mimetype="text/csv")
```

How could the error still happen?

I read from some posts (e.g., [How can I add a health check to a Sagemaker Endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558057/how-can-i-add-a-health-check-to-a-sagemaker-endpoint)
) saying that "ping response should return within 2 seconds timeout".

How can I increase the ping response timeout? And in general, what can I do to prevent the error from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Quick clarification, SageMaker Batch Transform and creating a Real Time Endpoint are two different facets. For [Batch Transform] you do not use a persistent endpoint rather create a transformer object that can perform inference on a large set of data. An example of the Bring Your Own approach with Batch can be seen [here](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aws_sagemaker_studio/sagemaker_studio_image_build/xgboost_bring_your_own/Batch_Transform_BYO_XGB.html).

Regardless of Batch or Real-Time the /ping must be passed. Make sure that you are loading your model in this route. Generally if your model is not loaded properly this leads to that health check error being emitted. Here's another [BYOC example](https://github.com/RamVegiraju/SageMaker-Deployment/tree/master/RealTime/BYOC/PreTrained-Examples/SpacyNER), in the predictor.py you can see me loading the model in the /ping route.

Lastly not sure what you mean by 20 instances simultaneously? Are you backing the endpoint with a 20 instance count?